# what is an error "Error: Unexpected token '}' in JSON at position 1923" in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am using `Ionic-2` framework. When I install any native plugin in my application it throws the following error in command line.

> Error: Unexpected token '}' in JSON at position 1923

I am not getting what is causing this error, now I'm unable to install any plugin.

Comment: Check line 19, position 23 of your files. Is there a `}`? Can you run `ionic serve`? Or does it throw the same error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem:

```
Error: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 1057
```

when I issued the command:

```
ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
```

The reason was I made a mistake by trying to comment a line of "`plugins/fetch.json`" by "`//`". Cerntainly, a json file couldn't be commented this way. However, Ionic 2 didn't tell you which file had the problem.

So, please check the json file Ionic might touch during the process, e.g. `package.json` & `plugins/fetch.json`

Make sure all the {} pair are matched.

Comment: hey thanks, this was exactly what happened in my case

Comment: in my case it was an error in fetch.json, thank you so much.

Comment: May be you can use `--verbose` to find out where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem when trying to execute `cordova build --release android`

Execute `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console` to solve it.